# Angular 13 Child and parent component get model from child component

Tags: angular, angular13

I created two components NewInvoiceComponent and InvoiceItemListComponent.
InvoiceItemListComponent is used for Invoice items (count,units,description,price)
I try to create dynamic add and remove inputs fields. Buttons Add and delete input fields works ok.
But there is any problem with get data from child component. When I submit  form the items in array invoiceItems are still null. I use [(ngModel)] in the InvoiceItemListComponents.

Is it possible use ngModel for this dynamic inputs ?
Or is it some problem with @output ?

**Parent component:**

```
    export class NewInvoiceComponent implements OnInit {
      public invoiceItems: InvoiceItem[] = [];
    
      constructor() { }
    
      ngOnInit(): void {
    
      }
    
      addInvoiceItem(): void {
        let next = 0;
    
        if (this.invoiceItems.length > 0) {
          next = this.invoiceItems.length;
        }
        this.invoiceItems.push({count: null, description: null, price: null, unit: null, id: next});
      }
    
      deleteInvoiceItem(item: InvoiceItem): void {
        this.invoiceItems = this.invoiceItems.filter(element => element.id !== item.id);
      }
    
      onSubmit(): void {
        console.log(this.invoiceItems);
      }
}
```

**parent .html**

```
<app-invoice-item-list [invoiceItemList]="invoiceItems" (onDelete)="deleteInvoiceItem($event)"></app-invoice-item-list>
<button class="btn btn-primary" type="button" (click)="addInvoiceItem()">New item</button>
<!-- another inputs -->
<div class="col-lg-12">
<button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Create invoice</button>
</div>
```

**child component invoice-item-list:**

```
export class InvoiceItemListComponent implements OnInit {
      @Input() invoiceItemList = [];
      // tslint:disable-next-line:no-output-on-prefix
      @Output() onDelete = new EventEmitter<any>();
      constructor() {
        console.log(this.invoiceItemList);
      }
    
      ngOnInit(): void {
      }
    
      onDeleteInvoiceItem(invoiceItem) {
        console.log(invoiceItem);
        this.onDelete.emit(invoiceItem);
      }
    
    }
```

**child .html**

```
<div class="row" *ngFor="let invoice of invoiceItemList">
  <div class="col-md-2">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label class="form-control-label" for="input-count">Count</label>
      <input id="input-count" name="count"  class="form-control form-control-alternative" [(ngModel)]="invoice.count" type="number">
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="col-md-2">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label class="form-control-label" for="input-type">Unit</label>
      <input id="input-type" name="type"  class="form-control form-control-alternative" type="text" placeholder="ks, hod" [(ngModel)]="invoice.unit">
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="col-md-4">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label class="form-control-label" for="input-description">Description</label>
      <input id="input-description" name="description"  class="form-control form-control-alternative" placeholder="Popis položky" type="text" [(ngModel)]="invoice.description">
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="col-md-2">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label class="form-control-label" for="input-item-price">Price</label>
      <input id="input-item-price" name="address"  class="form-control form-control-alternative" placeholder="Cena" type="text" [(ngModel)]="invoice.price">
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="col-md-2">
    <div class="form-group">
      <button class="btn btn-danger" type="button" (click)="onDeleteInvoiceItem(invoice)">Delete</button>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Angular is **PASS-BY-REFERENCE**.
You should be aware of that when you pass objects between components and use `[(ngModel)]`

In your example, you don't need to do: `@Output() onDelete = new EventEmitter<any>();`.

Since you are passing `invoiceItems` and using `[(ngModel)]` in child class, any changes it's done to  `@Input() invoiceItemList = [];` at child class will be reflected in  `invoiceItems` without emitting.

Then you would not need the following function:

```
 deleteInvoiceItem(item: InvoiceItem): void {
        this.invoiceItems = this.invoiceItems.filter(element => element.id !== item.id);
 }
```

Try removing all these.